# How to implement HTML5 required attribute with jQuery .submit() function at the same time

Tags: jquery, html, validation

When I tried to submit a form using the jQuery `submit()` function, the HTML5 required attribute is not working.

Comment: why should it? .submit() is going to assume that you know what you're doing and isn't going to enforce any html-level requirements.

Comment: Instead of worrying about votes...worry about creating a properly documented question. That includes providing relevant code. Then the votes will come.

Comment: thanks for the response @MarcB . . is there any way that i can use the html5 required functionality? it's just that in my situation . i will have to submit the form via jquery . . .and it's time consuming to create a script that will validate my text fields . .

Comment: @charlietfl ahhh okay . .i just want some reputation so i can put comments to other posts . .

Comment: @Juhana thanks . .it worked!!!